# Cannot type any special character or umlaut in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, special-characters

**Environment:**
I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with wmii 3.9 as GUI and uxterm as terminal with bash as shell.
The hardware is a Lenovo ThinkPad W500 with a Swissgerman keyboard layout (thus I need umlauts).
I am using ibus for Japansese input.

**Symthoms:**
When I type keys/chars like `~`,`^` in terminal *nothing* happens. If I press `ö` '`(arg: 6)`' appears, with `ä` nothing happens, with `ü` sometimes a command from the history appears.
 It is the same behaviour in all terminals I tested so far (gnome-terminal, xfce4-terminal, xterm). 
It works as desired in other X applications like chromium-browser, skype or texteditors.

**Additional information:**

```
> locale
LANG=de_CH.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

> setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+ch+inet(evdev)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)"    };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
};
```

Comment: I stumpled over the same problem within docker containers from `docker run -it --rm ubuntu bash` and `docker run -it --rm nginx:1.20.2 bash` and non of the provided solutions here solved the issue it. But from locales i found [this docker-related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52004330/2195180) where they claimed to just introduce locale settings via environment variables `-e LANG=C.UTF-8 -e LC_ALL=C.UTF-8` which worked, while setiting `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8` and `LANG=C.UTF-8` in the console didn't (no need for extra installs)

Comment: for reproducibility: I used `ubuntu:20.04`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was having a similar problem when connecting via ssh to Mac OS X using a terminal emulator. Although I'd set LANG to `de_DE.UTF-8` I couldn't type in any characters with umlauts.

The fix I found was to create/edit `~/.inputrc`  (or edit the following lines in `/etc/inputrc`):

```
set input-meta on
set output-meta on
set convert-meta off
```

Now I can type umlauts. I believe this applies to xterms in general.

Comment: Thank you, this fixes the umlaut problem! But I am still not able to type characters like ~, ^ or ¨.

Comment: It fixed this for me kind of too (after a new login) but there is still something odd: if I type `ö` I get an ö, but there seems to be a hidden character too: I can delete wich Backspace two characters although I only typed one `ö`. Entering `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8` in the commandline fises this for that session, but is gone in a new shell

Comment: @rubo77 add `export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8` to your `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 7):

Set the right locales with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

There you would select `de_DE.UTF-8` as your setting. That solves all problems ;)

*Info: Changing the value for `set convert-meta off` in `/etc/inputrc` is not completely working:

It fixed this kind of too, but there is still something odd: if I type `ö` I get an ö, but there seems to be a hidden character in front of the ö: I can delete wich Backspace two characters although I only typed one ö*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly I cannot test the outcome of your suggestion, since the system this problem occurred does not exist anymore. Furthermore, I do not understand, why changing the locale from de_CH.UTF-8 to de_DE.UTF-8 should change the situation.

Comment: Not sure, I had an english layout before. But maybe the ch layout also uses deadkeys for ö?

Comment: Yes, it does, de_CH is the the Swiss-German layout, it is very similar to to German layout.

Comment: I think this answer should stay for users that have a similar problem, but don't use the CH layout. I guess the solution is to run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` again (not the specific layout I used)

Comment: Agreed! I wish, I could test if it solves the problem.

Comment: I just tested and it didn't work for me...

Comment: @Raven, which terminal on which system and version?

Comment: Uhm the default terminal on Linux Mint 18.3 which I think is bash (or is the terminal something else?)

Comment: This worked for me, and I think it is the right way to go. The workaround with changing `.inputrc` introduced new problems in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Additionally to the mentioned answers it can be that your locales are not compiled. There are locale source files under /usr/share and compiled locale files under /usr/lib. Those under /usr/lib might be damaged or not compiled to fix that you can use localedef utility to compile the files. Or on Debian based systems dpkg-reconfigure.